# Ошибка в передаваемых параметрах

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def connect_db(self, user, password, db, host, port):
    url = 'postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'
    url = url.format(self, user, password, host, port, db)
    eng = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url, client_encoding='utf8')
    meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData(bind=eng, reflect=True)
```

**в дальнейшем коде**

```
self.connect_db(self, Login[0], Password[0], 'BaseADS', 'localhost', 5432)
```

**Ошибка**

[image: ошибка]

connect_db должен принимать 6 параметров, я и передаю 6 параметров. Почему питон думает, что там 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно будет не указывать вручную `self` в методе `connect_db`, т.е. нужно будет исправить на:

```
self.connect_db(Login[0], Password[0], 'BaseADS', 'localhost', 5432)
```

Когда у объекта создается метод, то в методе первым параметром будет передаваться ссылка на экземпляр самого объекта. Этот параметр традиционно называется `self`.

`self` является аналогом `this` в других популярных языках, например: `c++`, `java`, `c#`, и т.п. Но т.к. в питоне считается что явное лучше не явного, то ссылка на сам объект будет явно присутствовать.

Если же, в методе не нужно передавать `self`, то такой метод нужно сделать статичным, используя декоратор `@staticmethod`:

```
@staticmethod
def connect_db(user, password, db, host, port):
    url = 'postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'
    url = url.format(user, password, host, port, db)
    eng = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url, client_encoding='utf8')
    meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData(bind=eng, reflect=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

мб кому будет полезно - оставлю это тут(понять понял, объяснить не знаю как).
**self**.method(**self**, ....)
считаются как два аргумента,

```
 self.connect_db(Login[0], Password[0], 'BaseADS', 'localhost', 5432)
```

работает

Comment: Ответ добавил, кст, проблем с `url` в вашем методе не было? Там ведь `self` зачем то в `format` помещается, а в шаблоне указанно 5 значение, но `self` является шестым, да и наличие его в `url` кажется подозрительным

Comment: проблем с url не возникало, все работает. Я украл его со стороннего ресурса, пока что слабо разбираюсь в тонкостях. Благодарю за ответ, в силу большего содержания - сделаю его ответом.